# Run SQL Update Inside a For Loop

Tags: php, sql

Mission:  Verify that "players" have placed vintage promotional jpegs on their social media site(s). Doing so earns them crypto tokens towards game play. All non-verified postings are displayed on an administrator's dashboard with a checkbox if the listing has been visually verified and "Approved." The value of each checkbox is the database ID of the listing (see screen capture). Once the listings have been verified and the check box ticked, the page is POST(ed) to a query page where the default value "confirm" is changed from 0 to 1. This then awards them the designated tokens.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzWHS.jpg)

However, I haven't found the right formula of code to get the UDPATE to work. The checkbox values will display in "echo" mode, but the SQL won't function within the FOREACH loop.

```
    <?php
    
    $checked_arr = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $count = count($checked_arr);
    echo "There are ".$count." checkboxe(s) are checked <br>";
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $val)     {
          $sql = "UPDATE media SET confirm = 1 WHERE id = $val " ;
          echo "$val\n";
    ?>
```

Scoured the Net for working examples, including Stack Overflow, but to no avail. Assume there's a simple answer here, but as a novice PHP programmer, it eludes me.

Thank you in advance for suggestions.

Comment: `$sql` is just a SQL string. Do you execute it? You also are open to SQL injections what that, parameterize queries.

Comment: Where are you actually trying to execute the query? All you do here is build a query string but you never open a database connection or send the query on the open connection to be executed. Naming a variable `$sql` doesn't mean it will execute.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the IN operation in the conditional.

The only thing you would have to do is capture all the IDS and do an "implode" to give it the format that is needed for the sql.

for example:

```
<?php
$ids = [];
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $val){
  $ids[] = $val;
}
$values = implode(",", $ids); // => 'id1, id2, id3, ...'
// this is a massive update based on selected items
$sql = "UPDATE media SET confirm = 1 WHERE id IN ($values)";
?>
```

Comment: I don't know Php (excuse my ignorance), but `$sql=` sets the SQL statement  in a string; what part of the code submits it to the database (actions)?

Comment: Thanks, guys (or gals)!  It was both suggestions that finally solved the problem: the 'implode' and the 'where's the action.'

Comment: Here's the new working code:

Comment: <pre><code> if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $checklist) {
 
  $ids[] = $checklist;

 $values = implode(",", $ids); // => 'id1, id2, id3, ...'
  
 $sql = "UPDATE media SET confirm = 1 WHERE id IN ($values)";
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    
     echo "Records Update";
   
    } else {
     
     echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }       
        
    }
}</code></pre>